# Aptana Studio 3 Eclipse Plugin - Need an archived version

Tags: eclipse, aptana

For some reason, many of the plugins I try to install through Eclipse from update sites hang during installation. The progress bar stops and it shows a 0B/s download speed when it tries to get a certain jar for the installation. Sometimes I get a "read timed out" error. Other times the progress bar just sits for awhile and finally disappears once it times out with no error. (This is true both for Aptana Studio 3's plugin as well as the JRebel plugin. I have tried this both with Eclipse Indigo and Helios (both 64-bit for Windows 7) and have the same problem with both. I tried turning off my local firewall to no avail. Others in my company have been able to successfully install from these same update sites.

Does anyone have any idea what might be causing this problem? And, if not, does Aptana Studio 3 have an archive version of their plugin so I don't have to install from the update site?

Answer (score 7):

You could download the update site zip from http://download.aptana.com/studio3/plugin/install/index.html (click on the "Download Plugin Update Site").

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

You can download the plugin directly from their site... http://www.aptana.com/products/studio3/download. Just tick the "Eclipse Plug-in Version" bubble...

Comment: Nope! This does not give any option to download directly. Only instruction to download via eclipse